# Unable to find stacktrace when uploading with AWS TransferManager

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the [TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) to upload some files on my server to S3 asynchronously. The problem is that it is failing for an unknown reason and I am not seeing any exceptions in the logs.

I see a comment in the documentation for seeing the exception when the transfer fails. The problem is that this requires blocking the thread.

```
// Or you can block the current thread and wait for your transfer to
// to complete. If the transfer fails, this method will throw an
// AmazonClientException or AmazonServiceException detailing the reason.
myUpload.waitForCompletion();
```

I've tried using the ProgressListener, but that seems to only notify me when the transfer fails. I don't see any exceptions thrown.

Is there a way to view these exceptions without blocking?

Answer (score 2):

Once the ProgressListener notifies you that the upload is complete (or has failed), you can call `waitForCompletion` to get the result without blocking.

```java
public class FailureListener extends SyncProgressListener {

    public static void bind(Upload upload) {
        upload.addProgressListener(new FailureListener(upload));
    }

    private final Upload upload;

    public FailureListener(Upload upload) {
        this.upload = upload;
    }

    @Override
    public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
        if (progressEvent.getEventType() == ProgressEventType.TRANSFER_FAILED_EVENT) {
            AmazonClientException e = getException();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private AmazonClientException getException() {
        try {
            // Won't actually "wait" since the transfer has already failed.
            return upload.waitForException();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new Error("WTF?", e);
        }
    }
}
```